# NSArray Return Error

Tags: nsarray, swift2, ios9, xcode7

How else can I return the items in the array? I'm having trouble with the returning items as it's saying that I have used it before initializing it.

```
class func fetchEntities(className:NSString, withPredicate predicate:NSPredicate?, managedObjectContext:NSManagedObjectContext)->NSArray {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    let entetyDescription: NSEntityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(className as String, inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)!

    fetchRequest.entity = entetyDescription
    if (predicate != nil) {
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate!
    }

    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    let items:NSArray

    do {
        items = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
    }
    catch(let error as NSError) {
        NSLog(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    return items
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define array of type `ManagedObject` and store result in it as below. I have declared an array named `users` which is of type `ManagedObject` `User`

```
// Declare users array which stores objects of `User` class only.
var users  = [<User>]()

// Execute request and store result into array
users = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)

// return stored array
return users
```

i hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You should be returning `NSArray?` (i.e. nullable) as it can be `nul` if an exception is thrown:

```
do {
    items = try managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
}
catch(let error as NSError) {
    NSLog(error.localizedDescription)    // HERE!!!
}
return items
```